# can't load shared library libXt.so.6 - although it can be located

Tags: games, shared-library

## Starting binary -> can't open shared library

I want to start a binary:

```
$ my@mypc:~/Machinarium$ ./Machinarium
./Machinarium: error while loading shared libraries: libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

here

(Same happens when I try to start it via `linux32 ./Machinarium`. It is a 32bit linux binary and I have a 64bit machine. Same with sudo.)

---

## Locating the library (it exists)

I tried to locate it: (fourth line from the bottom is the important one)

```
me@mypc:~/Machinarium$ locate libXt
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6.0.0
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6.1.0
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6.0.0
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6.1.0
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6.0.0
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6.1.0
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6.0.0
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6.1.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6.1.0
```

So what happened? It's clearly there. Why can't it be found?

---

## Install i386 version explicitly

I thought since it's a folder labeled `x86_64` this might not be compatible to that 32bit game. So I installed the 32bit version explicitly. (Following [that stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17355914/7496806).)

```
me@mypc:~/Machinarium$ sudo apt install libxtst6:i386
libxtst6:i386 already is the newest version (2:1.2.3-1).
```

(translation by me. This is one line of what the very short answer by apt says.)

---

## Requirements check -> not found

I checked the requirements for the binary: (I only give you the important line of the output and ignore any other line, if you really need the rest I wonder what for, just tell me in the comments if needed!)

```
me@mypc:~/Machinarium$ ldd Machinarium
libXt.so.6 => not found
```

---

## Question

- Why doesn't the binary find the shared library?
- How to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the search on https://packages.ubuntu.com the *libXt.so.6* is located in [`libxt6` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libXt.so.6).

You can install it with

```
sudo apt install libxt6:i386
```

for 32-bit.

Comment: I never thought it could be that simple…
Thank you! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can