# VBoxClient: error while loading shared libraries: libXt.so.6:

Tags: package-management, virtualbox, shared-library

Through `VirtualBox` for many *Virtual Machines* for `Ubuntu` **Server** - for each one an upgrade was done from 20.04 to 22.04. The `apt update` and `apt upgrade` commands work fine. But just few days ago I did realize that if I execute the following command to all the *Virtual Machines*:

```
VBoxClient --version
```

arises the following error message

```
VBoxClient: error while loading shared libraries: libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

was reinstalled `VirtualBox Guest Additions` and the situation remains.

**Question**

- How fix this situation?

**Extra Question**

- Why this situation appeared? Is due the OS' *upgrade*?

**UPDATE**

In the post:

- [can't load shared library libXt.so.6 - although it can be located](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109393/cant-load-shared-library-libxt-so-6-although-it-can-be-located)

is indicated as solution execute the command

```
sudo apt install libxt6:i386
```

It shows

```
E: Unable to locate package libxt6:i386
```

Thus was executed

```
sudo apt install libxt6
```

And was installed.

But sadly even if the VM is restarted, the error remains

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't load shared library libXt.so.6 - although it can be located](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109393/cant-load-shared-library-libxt-so-6-although-it-can-be-located)

Comment: @user535733 see the `update` section

Comment: See workaround for vbguest plugin https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest/issues/425

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a fresh Debian 11, running in VirtualBox 7, I got just the same behaviour:

```
$ VBoxClient --version
VBoxClient: error while loading shared libraries: libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file
```

...after initially installing only the following packages:

```
apt-get install dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
```

Turns out I had to also install the following:

```
apt-get install libxt6 libxmu6
```

...and now I'm getting, without reboot:

```
$ VBoxClient --version
7.0.2r154219
```

Comment: Thank you - it worked directly with `sudo apt install libxt6 libxmu6`

Comment: Just being curious, how did you know why to use `libxmu6`?

Comment: `VBoxClient` was complaining that `libXmu.so.6` is missing...

Comment: @zb226  Thanks. I've ported your solution to workaround for vbguest plugin https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest/issues/425

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error.
Just install the missing `libxx` package.
You saw the error remains, probably because another `libxx` package is missing, and you need to continue install the new package. That's what I did.

Comment: Can you share the complete command?

Comment: I can't reproduce, so I can't give you the exact package name. But the main idea is, if you successfully installed `libxt6` using `sudo apt install libxt6` then run `VBoxClient --version` again, the error message should be **different**. In my case it's another lib-something package missing, so I just kept installing the next missing one :)

Comment: Did you read the `UPDATE` section in my post?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Based on your comment beblow @zb226 's answer, you clearly didn't pay attention to the error message